# Twilio Hangup up immediately with no busy signal

Tags: twilio

For my Twilio number I have TwiML App and I am using Flask as a backend to handle URL for incoming calls. My goal is to create behavior that for every incoming call it hangs up (and send sms, but this is not so relevant at the moment)
so far I used:

1. Twiml Response with Hangup ends with "busy signal"
2. Twiml Response with Reject ends with message "number you are calling is not available"
3. using twilio rest client (like in Twilio's example) client.calls.update("CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38", status="completed") also results in "busy signal"
4. twilio rest client: client.calls.hangup(twilio_call_sid) also results in "busy signal"

so I am running out of ideas and I can't believe that it's not possible to finished incoming call (without answering) clearly with no busy signal, or I am probably missing something.
I would appreciate any help

Comment: Hi, Megan from Twilio here. Just trying to understand your question. Is the behavior in the second item of your list undesirable?

Comment: Hi Megan, all behaviors in the list are undesirable. what I would like is that when somebody calls twilio number I immediately hangup and caller doesn't hear any sound (currently it hears busy sound), exactly the same behaviour when you have conversation and you hangup, there is no more any sound.

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is coming way late, but if you want to simply respond to incoming calls with an SMS you can use the [`<Sms>` TwiML verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms) to do so.

And then from the users perspective, gracefully end the call with [`<Hangup>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/hangup#hints).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Sms from="+14105551234" to="+14105556789" action="URL_TO-HANGUP_TWIML">Say hello StackOverflow.</Sms>
</Response>
```